# Blazor AuthorizeView not updating If the page not reloaded

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

In my StickyMenu component IU have the following code

```
<AuthorizeView>
  <NotAuthorized>
    Not Authorized
  </NotAuthorized>
  <Authorized>
   Authorized
   @(context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value)
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I set up a CustomAuthStateProvider like this

```
 public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    public async Task<Utenti?> GetUser()
    {
        var userSessionStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<Utenti>(Constants.sessionStorageUser);
        return userSessionStorageResult.Success ? userSessionStorageResult.Value : null;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Utenti? userSession = await GetUser();
            if (userSession == null)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }
            else
            {
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {                    
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession?.Nome ?? String.Empty),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userSession?.email ?? String.Empty),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userSession.IdUtente.ToString())
            }, "CustomAuth"));

                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateAuthenticationState(Utenti parUser)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
        if (parUser != null)
        {
            _sessionStorage.SetAsync(Constants.sessionStorageUser, parUser);
            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {                   
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, parUser.Nome),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, parUser.email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, parUser.IdUtente.ToString())
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync(Constants.sessionStorageUser);
            claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
        }

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        
    }
}
```

When I login whit LoginPage I call this method

```
public void Login()
    {
        Utenti u = Utenti.Login(Username, StringUtil.encryptpass(Password));
        if (u != null)
        {
            var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
            customAuthStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState(u);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/",true);
        }
    }
```

And in the menu I see Authorize and the user name

THE PROBLEM is that, when I put something in the cart, I have to add a temporary user (now in the example I force the Login with an existing username and password) and I update the StickyMenu component.

```
public async void AddToCart()
    {
        Utenti ut = Utenti.Login("email", StringUtil.encryptpass("password"));

        if (ut.IdUtente > 0)
        {
            var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
            customAuthStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState(ut);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that, If I don't reload the page calling

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo(someurl,true);
```

the AutorizeView doesn't change.

How I can fix this problem?

---

[SIMPLE PROJECT ON GITHUB](https://github.com/ferrarinim/ExampleAuthorizeView)

Comment: RenderMode?  What version of Net? If Net8, What  what settings are you using for Interactivity location?  What Interactive render modes are you using.  This sounds like a Static SSR issue.

Comment: render-mode is ServerPrerendered

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Net version 7

Comment: updating to net8 nothing changes

Comment: You have a bit of an async problem. Pretty much everywhere you have `Task.FromResult()`, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your other question this is your Layout:

```cs
<header>
  <StickyMenu></StickyMenu>
</header>

<main>
  <Loader Loading=@IsLoading></Loader>
  @Body
</main>
```

As configured `StickyMenu` will only be rendered once when the Layout first renders.  It will not re-render when Layout re-renders because it's parameter state hasn't changed: there are no parameters.

If you want it to re-render it, you need a mechanism to trigger a render.  The most appropriate in the context is a handler registered on the `AuthenticationState` change event.

Here's a similar control from a demo Authorization project of mine.  `OnUserChanged` is registered on  the `AuthState.AuthenticationStateChanged` event.  It gets the new user and calls `StateHasChanged` to render the component.

> Note implementing `IDisposable` and de-registering the handler in `Dispose`.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@namespace Blazr.Demo.Authorization.UI

<span class="text-nowrap ms-3">
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            Hello, @(this.user.Identity?.Name ?? string.Empty)
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            Not Logged In
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</span>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authTask { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider authState { get; set; } = default!;

    private ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(authTask);
        var state = await authTask;
        this.user = state.User;
        authState.AuthenticationStateChanged += this.OnUserChanged;
    }

    private async void OnUserChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> state)
        => await this.GetUser(state);

    private async Task GetUser(Task<AuthenticationState> state)
    {
        var authState = await state;
        this.user = authState.User;
        await this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => authState.AuthenticationStateChanged -= this.OnUserChanged;
}
```

The [slightly dated] demo project is [here - Blazr.Demo.Authorization](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization/).

### Update based on the MRE Repo.

Your code is pretty unconventional and left field so it took a while to start to read.

Your immediate issue is in here:

```cs
        public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(Utenti parUser)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
            if (parUser != null)
            {
                await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("user", parUser);
                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("IdUser", parUser.IdUtente.ToString()),
                    new Claim("UserStatus", parUser.Stato),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, parUser.Nome),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, parUser.email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, parUser.IdUtente.ToString())
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("user");
                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }
```

If you refactor this code into something a little more readable, the problem becomes more obvious.

```cs
        public async Task _UpdateAuthenticationState(Utenti parUser)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
            if (parUser != null)
            {
                await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("user", parUser);

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("IdUser", parUser.IdUtente.ToString()),
                    new Claim("UserStatus", parUser.Stato),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, parUser.Nome),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, parUser.email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, parUser.IdUtente.ToString())
                };

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                //var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CustomAuth");

                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            }
            else
            {
                await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("user");

                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }
```

You have provided no `AuthenticationType`, so the user is unauthorized.

There are no prizes for writing hard to read, difficult to debug code.  The compiler will refactor and optimize the hell out of it.  You don't need to try to.

The only loser is you.  It's a lesson I've learnt the hard way!

Comment: sorry but I didn't see the answer. I tryied the  github code: the OnUserChanged fires when I login the user but the page shows Not Authorized again.

Comment: Have a look at the code in the Repo.  The `UserBar` doses something similar to your `StickyMenu`.  If you could get you issue down to a [mre] I [and others] would almost certainly be able to find the issue.  At the moment nothing in your code jumps out at me.

Comment: I added the simple project on GITHUB
https://github.com/ferrarinim/ExampleAuthorizeView
Here you can see that clicking on Login Automatically AuthorizeView doesn't change
THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP YOU'RE GIVING ME

Comment: instead, if you reload the page the AuthorizeView shows the correct value

Comment: the CustomAuthentication was written following a youtube tutorial (I don't remember which one) I probably didn't fully understand the topic. However adding CustomType everything works correctly. Thank you so much for your patience.